# How can i add div inside a facebook iframe

Tags: php, facebook-iframe

i need to change my iframe background color like a facebook popup using blue and white. how can i configure that and is this possilble instead of  using background image

here i have added the codes for your review

```
<div id="fb">
<div id="fb-close"></div>
<div id="fblike">
<div id="fbclose"></div>
<div class="eliminater"></div>
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=<?php echo esc_url(get_option('fb_likeurl')); ?>&amp;width=402&amp;height=255&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color=blue;&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;appId=329902783740649" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" style="border-width: medium medium 71px; border-style: none; border-color: blue; -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; border-image: none; margin-top: -21px; width: 397px; height: 239px; margin-left: 8px;background-color:#fff;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

css files are here below

```
#fb {
display:block;
background-color:;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:99999;
}

#fb-close {
width:100%;
height:100%
}

#fblike {
background:white;
width:420px;
height:270px;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-135px 0 0 -210px;
}

#fbclose {
float:right;
cursor:pointer;
background:url(../images/fanclose.png) repeat;
height:15px;
padding:20px;
position:relative;
padding-right:40px;
margin-top:-20px;
margin-right:-22px;
}

.eliminater{
height:1px;
width:366px;
margin:0 auto;
background:#fff;
margin-top:16px;
position:relative;
margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: If you give me your password and username I can do it for you :)...Do you have a code to show us? We can find solutions here not reading minds..

Comment: now u can view my code Che Jug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this i think this works fine.

```
var html = "<style>Background-image:(url:yoururl);</style>";

$("#frameID").contents().find("head").append(html);
```

Comment: can i use image as a background instead of div

Comment: @raj this code is work or not.

Comment: ya its working thanks harshit

Comment: @raj Please consider green-checking this answer if it served your purpose and don't forgot to up vote.

Comment: thanks harshit. i will catch u soon with another quest